# Importance of the empty string

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

In the sense of a string distinct from a null reference string, what is the importance of an empty string in CS (and specially in formal languages)?

Why do you need a separate concept, that of 'empty string', which even has it's own Greek letter (ε)?

Couldn't just an EOL character replace it?

Comment: What makes you think that there is only one "correct" definition for the concept?

Comment: @Raphael: what makes you think that I think that?

Comment: I was reading between the lines. A better comment may have been: have you tried defining formal languages that way and proving some basic theorems?

Comment: What do you mean by "null reference string"? Is that a programming
language concept ? What do you mean by a "separate concept" ?
Separate from what ?  What difference do you make between the greek
character ε and the EOL character, except for the fact that they have
different uses in the representation of texts?  Finally, what do you
mean by "need", as we can often do without specific concepts or
notations, and get things done? Do we need high level programming
languages? Well, they make programming easier in many ways, but are
not Undispensable. You also seem to confuse syntax and semantics.

Comment: Null reference string: would be a string variable pointing to a null (that means non existing value). Separate concept: you don't have a term for a string of length 44, but you bother to give a string of the length 0 a name. Following the same line of thought, it has to be important, otherwise you wouldn't give it a term, nor a Greek letter, unless you planned to use it repeatedly. Regarding EOL: if EOL could cover all functions that the ε has, then the latter would be redundant.

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the above comment and in my answer, you are confusing
syntax and semantics (and so do @Raphael -apparently- and two answers). J.-E. Pin
explains the structural importance of the empty string, which
justifies specific consideration to be able to denote it. It can be
done in various ways (see my answer) … ε or EOL or null reference or…,
depending on whether you write theoretical text on paper or whether
you implement a string manipulation program. There is no separate
concept (semantics) but only, sometimes, a specific notation (syntax).
I will add some details in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

There is a **mathematical meaning** for the empty string. Indeed the concatenation product of words is an associative operation. But this operation also has a **neutral element**, namely the empty word. For this reason, the empty word is also frequently denoted by $1$, which allows one to write, for each word $u$, 
$$
1 \cdot u = u = u \cdot 1
$$

Of course, if the alphabet is $\{0, 1\}$, it is not a good idea to denote the empty word by $1$ and this is probably the reason why the notation $\varepsilon$ (or sometimes $\lambda$) was introduced. But as Yuval Filmus pointed out, the empty word is a word of length $0$, that is, it contains no letter.

It is certainly disturbing to denote the empty word by $1$ (or by a greek letter $\varepsilon$ or $\lambda$), but you have to take it as a conventional notation, in the same way you denote the empty set by $\emptyset$.

Comment: It's worth noting that $(\Sigma^*, \cdot)$ is a monoid. Investigating algebraic properties of formal languages can yield interesting results, e.g. semiring parsing.

Answer (score 9):

The empty string is like zero. It represents "nothing" but is a fundamental concept. As a very simple example, a word $a$ is a prefix of a word $b$ if $b = aw$ for some word $w$. If you don't allow the empty string, a word wouldn't be a prefix of itself.

The EOL character is a character in a specific character set. If we're interested in strings over $\{0,1\}$, we have no EOL. Additionally, EOL is a character, so a string consisting of EOL is not empty.

Comment: Whether a word is a prefix of itself is a matter of definition. If you
decide not to consider the empty string, you have to change some
definitions accordingly to enable a consistent variant of the theory
of strings. - - The character EOL can indeed represent the empty
string. Representations can use any appropriately structured device. I
can use the characters z,e,r,o, and n to represent strings over $\{0,1\}$,
for example with "onezeroone" to represent what is usually noted "101"
and "none" for the empty string. Not that I recommand it.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but some definitions are "better" than others. And there are reasons. I'm giving one such reason.

Comment: Not sure which point you are answering. It seems to be only the first.
If you are not allowing the empty string, your definition of prefix is
most probably inadequate. Or can you give a reason why it should be
better?  The real reason you should give to justify that the empty
string is fundamental is that it is harder (but most likely possible)
to develop the theory without it. For example you have to give a more
complex definition of what it means for a string to be a prefix of
another. It is a more subtle point. Think of the Greeks doing
arithmetics without zero.

Comment: You can also justify the usual definition of prefix vs. yours, which is usually called proper prefix. But your example regarding zero gives it all - life is so much easier with it.

Comment: **If the empty string is not allowed**, my _definition of proper prefix_
is the usual definition of prefix (when empty string is allowed), and
my _definition of prefix_ is that u is a prefix of v iff u is a proper
prefix of v or equal to v. **The point is to remain semantically
consistent with the theory that allows for the empty string**. Yes, life is
easier with the empty string ...  but things are not different without it in the
way you seemed to imply in your remark about a word no longer being a
prefix of itself. I think it is an important point.

Comment: You do have a point, but I don't think it's as important as you claim. It's like deciding whether $0$ is a natural number or not.

Answer (score 6):

Using an end-of-line (EOL) character is equivalent in terms of expressive power – anything you can do with the empty word $\varepsilon$, you could redefine to do with EOL instead – but using it would be a monumental pain in the butt. The conventional definitions are:

> An *alphabet* is a finite set $\Sigma$ of symbols. A *string* $s$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ is a finite sequence $s_1\dots s_\ell$, where each $s_i\in\Sigma$. We write $|s|$ for the *length* of $s$, with $|s_1\dots s_\ell|=\ell$; the unique word of length zero is denoted $\varepsilon$. A *substring* of $s_1\dots s_\ell$ is any string $s_i\dots s_j$, where $1\leq i\leq j\leq \ell$. The *concatenation* of strings $s_1\dots s_\ell$ and $t_1\dots t_m$ is the string $s_1\dots s_\ell t_1\dots t_m$ of length $\ell+m$.

Compare this with:

> Let $\dashv$ be a distinguished *end of line* symbol. An *alphabet* is a finite set $\Sigma$ of symbols such that ${\dashv}\in\Sigma$.  A *string* $s$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ is a finite sequence $s_1\dots s_\ell$ where $s_i\in\Sigma\setminus\{{\dashv}\}$ for $i<\ell$ and $s_\ell={\dashv}$.  We write $|s|$ for the *length* of $s$, with $|s_1\dots s_\ell|=\ell-1$. A *substring* of $s_1\dots s_\ell$ is any string $s_i\dots s_j{\dashv}$, where $1\leq i\leq j< \ell$. The *concatenation* of strings $s_1\dots s_\ell$ and $t_1\dots t_m$ is the string $s_1\dots s_{\ell-1} t_1\dots t_m$ of length $\ell+m-2$.

Note the extra fiddliness and the potential for off-by-one errors, especially in the definition of concatenation. Also, consider defining automata over these terminated strings. In addition to checking whether its input has whatever properties the language requires, any automaton must now check that the last character of the input is ${\dashv}$, which will (I think) add two states to every automaton.

The empty string $\varepsilon$ has the same role as zero does in the natural numbers. It's the identity for the most basic operation (concatenation for strings, addition for naturals). This is important if you want to build any kind of algebraic structure, such as [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) or [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), which gives access to a large area of potentially useful mathematical results.  More straightforwardly, it makes a great base-case for inductions, since the hypothesis is often trivial for the empty string.  Indeed, when you do induction on strings, you're implicitly using the following inductive definition of $\Sigma$-strings:

- $\varepsilon$ is a $\Sigma$-string;
- if $s$ is a $\Sigma$-string and $\sigma\in\Sigma$, then $s\sigma$ is a $\Sigma$-string.

That also becomes more fiddly with terminated strings:

- ${\dashv}$ is a $\Sigma$-string;
- if $s{\dashv}$ is a $\Sigma$-string and $\sigma\in\Sigma\setminus\{{\dashv}\}$, then $s\sigma{\dashv}$ is a $\Sigma$-string.

Of course, you could do it the other way round and say that if $s$ is a string, then so is $\sigma s$. At that point, there's little to choose between terminated and unterminated strings but your induction might be better suited to adding characters on the end than the beginning.

Terminated strings are fine for programming with but they're not well suited to mathematics. When you're programming, you need some way of knowing when the string $s_1\dots s_\ell$ ends; when you're doing mathematics, it's obvious that $s_\ell$ is the last character from the way the string is written.

---

I've just noticed that you ask about the difference between a null reference and the empty string. A null reference is no string at all; the empty string is a string but it has no characters on it.  If you like, it's the difference between having a blank piece of paper (empty string) and having no paper at all (null reference).

Comment: IMO, the first part of your answer is misguided. The conventional
definition aims at defining abstractedly what a string is,
independently of how it is represented. The second definition is a
formal way to define one possible notation for it, but is nothing you
want for reasoning about strings. You are reinforcing a confusion
between syntax and semantics suggested by the somewhat awkward
question of the OP. The rest of your answer suffers the same problem.

Comment: In your last paragraph, you repeat the confusion between syntax and
semantics. Empty string is an abstract concept, and it could well be
represented in the conputer by a null reference, while non-empty
strings are represented by whatever is deemed convenient. The only
requirement is that string manipulation functions are written
accordingly so that the mathematical semantics of strings is adequately
respected. Note that paper too is only for representing strings. Abstract
mathematical entities are not of this world.

Comment: @babou As I stated ("anything you can do with the empty word $\varepsilon$, you could do with EOL instead"), the two options are semantically equivalent and I discuss what this semantic role is (e.g., the identity for the concatenation operator). Separately, I discuss how EOL is syntactically inconvenient. In what way is this confusing syntax with semantics?

Comment: The first definition is a standard one for the abstract concept. It
does not (have to) say anything about the way string are actually
represented. The OP is concerned with representation, and, in the
second definition, you are mimicking a proposed representation as if
it were the abstract definition of the concept, which is of course
more awkward. Symbol $\dashv$ should not be in $\Sigma$, but only be a
notational device used to terminate string representations (possibly a very
minor inconvenience) so that the notation is uniform for the empty
string. You did confuse syntax and semantics.

Comment: As I said, your statement about the syntactic inconvenience of EOL is
unwarranted. You created the problems by using an inadequate
definition (your second definition for strings). In my (rewritten)
answer, towards the end, I give the definition you should have been
using, which shows that these problems do not exist. The ⊣ must be part
of the notation, not a symbol in the represented string.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: the empty *set* (i.e. the set of strings which contains no strings) is like zero, but the empty *string* (i.e. the set of strings which contains one zero-length string) is like one.

One way to axiomatise formal languages is as an idempotent semiring. A semiring is a structure with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$, and two distinguished elements $0$ and $1$, and obeys the following axioms. First off, $+$ is a commutative monoid with identity $0$:

$$(A + B) + C = A + (B + C)$$
$$0 + A = A + 0 = A$$
$$A + B = B + A$$

Secondly, $\cdot$ is a monoid with identity $1$:
$$(A\cdot B)\cdot C = A\cdot(B\cdot C)$$
$$1\cdot A = A\cdot 1 = A$$
Multiplication left and right distributes over addition:
$$A\cdot (B + C) = (A\cdot B) + (A\cdot C)$$
$$(A + B)\cdot C = (A\cdot C) + (B\cdot C)$$
Multiplication by 0 annihilates:
$$0\cdot A = A\cdot 0 = 0$$
and finally, addition is idempotent:
$$A + A = A$$

"Addition" can be interpreted as set union and "multiplication" can be interpreted as string concatenation.

Oh, and the link goes very deep. The Kleene closure operator, which is intuitively defined as:

$$A^* = 1 + A + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots$$

behaves like exponentiation. Think of the power series of $e^x$, plus the fact that addition is idempotent.

Terminal characters behave like variables. In particular, we can define evaluation at zero:

$$a(0) = 0$$
$$(AB)(0) = A(0) B(0)$$
$$(A+B)(0) = A(0) + B(0)$$
$$A^*(0) = 1$$

Given a regular expression $E$, $E(0)$ is either $0$ or $1$. It is $1$ if the empty string is a member of $E$, and $0$ otherwise.

We can also define a derivative, called the Brzozowski derivative:

$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial a} = 1$$
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial a} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial (A+B)}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial a}$$
$$\frac{\partial AB}{\partial a} = A(0) \frac{\partial B}{\partial a}  + \frac{\partial A}{\partial a} B$$
$$\frac{\partial A^*}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial a} A^*$$

The only odd rule here is the one for multiplication. It's almost like the familiar product rule; the difference is due to the fact that concatenation is non-commutative.

What the derivative intuitively means is that $\frac{\partial E}{\partial a}$ is the set of strings in $E$ which start with the symbol $a$, but with that $a$ removed. So $a \frac{\partial E}{\partial a}$ is the set of strings in $E$ which start with $a$.

Thinking about it for a moment, if ${a\ldots z}$ is the alphabet, then:

$$E = E(0) + a \frac{\partial E}{\partial a} + b \frac{\partial E}{\partial b} + \cdots + z \frac{\partial E}{\partial z}$$

This is Taylor's theorem, only for regular languages. Moreover, it is also a rule for creating DFAs directly from regular expressions! $E(0)$ is $1$ if and only if the initial state is a final state, and the other terms are the transitions.

One remarkable thing about this is that the familiar regular expression operators (plus some less familiar ones, such as set intersection and set difference) are *completely* determined by their derivatives, plus their evaluation at zero. This is what we'd expect from the fundamental theorem of calculus, but it's interesting to see it here too.

Incidentally, this theory scales up to context-free and recursive languages too, but you need a bit more machinery for that which I won't go into here.

Answer (score 4):

## A fundamental question about mathematics

*This answer was reorganized after the OP gave more precisions as to
the meaning and intent of his question. I also comment other answers
here, as it is awkward to do so in the usual comment format. Commenting them also gives extra insight into the relevant issues.*

### In a nutshell

Your intuition is quite correct that the empty string plays a special
role in the study of strings and formal languages, and that is the
reason why it is often given a special name or notation. Strings over
a given set of symbols form an algebraic structure called a monoid,
with the concatenation operation which has a neutral element: the
empty string. See the [answer by J.-E. Pin](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19510).

You are also correct that there could be many other notations or
representation for it. The choice of representation is dictated by
convenience, perspicuity and simplification of discourse, reasoning
and computation.

One such convenience, as you rightfully wonder, is having a uniform
notation for all strings, including the empty string. This can be
achieved in several ways, whether on paper or in the
computer. Terminating strings with a special symbol supposed not to
belong to the set of symbols included in the strings is one way of
doing it. I guess this is what you suggest with EOL.  This was done
some 45 years ago by Denis Ritchie for the programming language C,
except that he used the byte 0, also noted NUL or ^@, rather than EOL.

In text it can be done with surrounding quotes, or with a final
turnstyle $\dashv$. Note however that while the $\dashv$ alone will
denote the empty string, it terminates then all strings, which is not
the case for the use of the letter ε. They do not play exactly the
same syntactic role.

In principle, such a termination symbol as EOL, ^@ or $\dashv$ cannot
be also a symbol belonging to a string, unless you add more complex
representation mechanisms.

In the computer, the null reference string could be used to represent
the empty string. Otherwise it is only a programming concept that has
nothing to do with the abstract concept of string.

However your question was a bit confusing and not too well
stated. Talking of a "*separate concept*" hints at semantic issues
rather than syntactic reresentation. And you were mixing textual,
printed representations, which use εbut not EOL, with computer
representation which do the opposite.

### With many more details

This is a strange question. In its way, it also raises one or two fundamental
issues about mathematics.

Understanding such issues is non obvious, as witnessed by the
inadequacies of some answers given by obviously competent users, and
the inadequacies of the question itself. This is what attracted me to
this question.

These two issues are concerned with :

- proper understanding of the respective **roles and uses of syntax and
  semantics** in mathematics and programming;
- proper understanding of the effect of **"removing a concept from an
  existing theory"**.

The second issue, which has to do with semantics, has probably been
addressed by logicians, and possibly by historians of science. But I
do not recall seeing it formally addressed (or possibly I did not
recognized it).

A confusion between syntax and semantics probably arose from the fact
that the OP talks of a "*separate concept*" where he should rather
talk of a "*separate notation*". Such a mistake is probably fair in
his case as he is trying to understand issues. But it further confused some
users who answered, clearly Yuval Filmus and myself, as we took the word
"concept" for what it is supposed to mean.

### About Semantics

*I realize now that the next paragraph is not about the question you
 intended; but it is the question you wrote, and which is to be understood as
 semantics, and was by several people, while you meant syntax (to be addressed in
 the syntax part below).*

Let's start with your
question "**Why do you need a separate concept, that of 'empty string'?**", which I understood as: *"could we use strings, in theory and in programming, without ever considering the empty string?"*, as apparently did Yuval Filmus.

**The fact is, we often do not need the empty string**, but it is generally more convenient to have it. Most of the theory could probably be developed
without ever considering empty strings. After all, a lot of
[arithmetics was developed by the Greeks without considering
zero as a number](http://yaleglobal.yale.edu/about/zero.jsp). Zero was introduced syntactically and semantically
only a few centuries later in India. Extending the number system is not just introducing new
concepts, but also a way of simplifying the understanding and use of
old concepts. Introducing zero and the negative numbers made it easier
to understand the properties of the natural positive numbers, and so
on. Some properties of functions on the reals (such as convergence of
series) are much easier to analyze and understand when you consider
the extension to complex numbers.

So introducing new concepts and extensions in mathematics is often a
good way of making theories simpler (and usually more powerful for
expressing problems).

Introducing the empty string along with "natural strings" will
simplify theories built on strings, and that is good enough a reason.
Typically, as stated in other answers, having the empty string enables
us to consider strings as representatives (models) of well known
algebraic structures (monoids), and apply directly all known results
about such structures. Indeed, as noted by J.-E. Pin, the empty string
is directly related to the concatenation operation on strings (and I
would add, in the same way that zero is related to the addition of
integers).

We do not or may not need the empty string, but it is a lot more
convenient to do mathematics with it than without it. And this is also
true of programming (which is a form of mathematics aiming at producing
constructive proofs).

**A matter of consistency**

However *I disagree with the [answer of Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19509)* regarding the
effect of not allowing for the concept of an empty string, in the same
way that the Greeks would not consider a number zero. Introducing zero
as a new number would not have been acceptable if it had changed the
known results of arithmetics. At best it would have been considered a
different theory, with its own purpose.

Similarly, a theory of strings should give consistent results whether it allows for the empty string or not. But both approaches should use
consistent definitions for that to be apparent and meaningful, and Yuval Filmus did
not do that.

**When the empty string is allowed**, the *usual definition of prefix* is:

> A string u is a **prefix** of a string v iff there is a string w such that
>   u.w=v

where the dot denotes the string concatenation. This allows for a
string being a prefix of itself by taking w=ε (the empty string). Then you can define:

> A string u is a **proper prefix** of a string v iff it is a
>   prefix of v and not equal to v.

However, **when the empty string is not allowed**, you have to state these
definitions consistently, but differently. For example:

> A string u is a **proper prefix** of a string v iff there is a
>   string w such that u.w=v

Note that w must have at least one symbol. Then you can define:

> A string u is a **prefix** of a string v iff u is a proper prefix of
>     v or u=v.

With such consistent definitions, a word remains a prefix of itself,
even when the empty string is not allowed in the theory.

So the point to be made is not that not allowing the empty
string changes the properties of strings (at least not in such a
trivial way) as asserted by Yuval Filmus. The point is much more that it makes the study of
strings more complicated, in the same way that arithmetics is more
complicated when you cannot talk of zero.

### About Syntax

The second issue is syntactic. How should strings be represented, on
paper or in the computer. In particular, assuming we agree that it is useful to have the concept of an empty string, how should it be represented syntactically so that we can talk or write about it.

The question actually arises for all mathematical concepts: how should
they be represented so that we can talk or write about them, and do so
as conveniently as possible. Much of the evolution of mathematics is
also related to improvement of syntax, of the representation of
concepts.  A trivial example is the awkwardness of doing arithmetics
with the ancient Roman representation of integers.

A first answer regarding the empty string is that you may want that to
be consistent with the representation of other strings. Typically, the
representation of a string will include the sequence of symbols in the
strings plus some additional notation, such as quotes : "*gattaca*" for
example. It then becomes quite natural to represent the empty string
as "".

If you rather represent the above example as *gattaca*$\dashv$, then the
natural representation for the empty string is $\dashv$ (as noted implicitly by David Richerby).

So the question about the need to introduce a *separate notation*
(rather than a *separate concept*, as actually written) has a negative
answer. No, it is not needed. Uniform notation, uniform
representation, is possible for all strings, including the empty
string.

However, if you simply represent the string by the sequence of included
symbols, such as *gattaca*, with no other characters, then the empty string would become
invisible syntactically, which is rather inconvenient. Then it is
necessary to introduce some specific notation, such as the Greek
letter ε or some other name.

Similarly, when studying strings abstractedly, it is a bit awkward to use "" to
represent the empty string, if only because it does not make for nice
and clear sentences in oral speech, when scientists talk to each
other, which is supposed to happen on occasion. Hence it is nicer to
give it a name. Saying *empty string* might do, but is awkward in
writing. Hence the habit of using a single letter symbol as is often
done in mathematics to denote entities of specific relevance,

The suggestion to represent the empty word by EOL is essentially the
same as representing it by $\dashv$. It is simply a representation of
strings with a special terminating character.  EOL is just a special character
"somehow available in computers".

As noted above for Roman integer arithmetics, the choice of a representation should be
dictated by convenience, expecially in an algorithmic
environment. There are many way to represent strings in general, and
the empty string in particular, in the computer. From a theoretical
standpoint, it does not matter much which you choose. From a practical
standpoint, it is essential to choose one that will make string
operations and manipulation more efficient. This is a basic issue in
any class on algorithms and data structures.

### On the confusion of syntax and semantics

The [answer by David Richerby](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19512) is interesting for its confusion of
syntax and semantics.

He tries to introduce the syntactic use of EOL suggested in the question, which he
replaces by the symbol $\dashv$, but he strangely mixes it with the
definition of the semantic domain of strings, making what is supposed
to be only a notation part of that semantic domain.

His second definition should actually have been the following:

> An *alphabet* is a finite set $\Sigma$ of symbols. A
>     *string* $s$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ is a finite
>     sequence of $\ell$ symbols $s_i$, where $0\le\ell$, $1\le i\le \ell$ and
>     $s_i\in\Sigma$ for all values of $i$. It is noted $s_1\dots
>   s_\ell\dashv$ where $\dashv$ is a special character not denoting a
>     symbol in $\Sigma$. We write $|s|$ for the *length* of
>     $s$, defined by $|s_1\dots s_\ell\dashv|=\ell$. A *substring* of $s_1\dots
>   s_\ell\dashv$ is any string $s_i\dots s_j\dashv$, where $1\leq i\leq
>   j\leq \ell$. The *concatenation* of strings $s_1\dots s_\ell\dashv$
>     and $t_1\dots t_m\dashv$ is the string $s_1\dots s_\ell t_1\dots
>   t_m\dashv$ of length $\ell+m$.
>     Note that as a consequence, the unique string of length
>     zero is denoted  $\dashv$.

This definition is just a notational variant of the conventional
definition given by David Richerby. It does not introduce any
complexity or "*extra fiddliness*" and changes nothing to automata
theory, for the simple reason that $\dashv$ is part of the notation,
not a symbol in the strings. And it does give a uniform notation for
all strings, including the empty one.

Yuval Filmus makes a similar error [in his second remark](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19509), since EOL is
intended as a syntactic notational device for representing strings,
not as a symbol in strings, while $\{0,1\}$ concerns the list of
symbols that can constitute strings, semantically.

### To summarize answers

[J.-E. Pin's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19510) is quite correct, but it addresses only one part of the
question, regarding the importance of the empty string. It does not address
the possibility of a uniform notation.

The answers of [Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19509) and [David Richerby](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19512) confusing syntax and
semantics, thus erroneously rejecting the suggestion of the OPś
question to use EOL. Also Yuval Filmus'argument to assert the semantic
importance of the empty string is very disputable. Though it deos make some sense, David Richerby's remark on the use of the null reference is also somewhat unwarranted: it could well be used to represent the empty string, provided the code is written accordingly.

The [answer by Pseudonym](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19589) is theoretical overkill regarding the
importance of the empty string in formal language, but does not
actually discuss the issues raised by the question.

As for [my own answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19587), I can only hope it addresses adequately the issues
and contains no error, but it is far far too long.

Comment: Incidentally, I went into as much detail as I did because I wanted to dispute Yuval Filmus' statement that the empty string is "like zero", because it isn't. You're right that I didn't touch on the final question, though. In my defence, this is CS, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @Pseud I think Yuval Filmus meant it in a weaker way. At any rate, what zero
is or is not (to speak loosely) depends on what kind of
mathematical structures you look at, and the same is true of the empty
string. His answer was fair in that respect, imho. Your point was
interesting, though, but possibly a bit heavy for the OP. BTW, I try
not to leave questions with erroneous or disputable answers without
noting it somewhere for more naive readers, or correcting it if the
answer is mine. I know my answer was unduly long, but did you
find erroneous or disputable statements in what you read of it.