# What is the importance of the empty string in CFG derivations?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, syntax

**NOTE:** This question is **NOT** the same as this other [nearly-identically worded question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505/importance-of-the-empty-string) with some amazing answers. I learned a *lot* from it regarding the mathematical importance of the empty string, but my question is specifically regarding its usage and purpose in a context-free grammar.

**Update:** After @Raphael's comments, maybe a better way to word my question is this: If the presence of the empty string in a non-terminal's RHS derivation is intended to remove the non-terminal from the resulting string, *why* would one want to do this? In what case would it make sense to remove a non-terminal?

**Original Question:**

I had an assignment to create a non-deterministic derivation, which I created as follows:

\begin{align}
A \rightarrow aAaBaC \ | \ aAaBc \ | \ aAaBC \ | \ aABC \ | \ d
\end{align}

This I then left-factored into the following deterministic grammar:

\begin{align}
A & \rightarrow aAA{'} \ | \ d \\
A' & \rightarrow aBA'' \ | \ BC \ | \ \epsilon \\
A'' & \rightarrow aC \ | \ c \ | \ C \ | \ \epsilon 
\end{align}

This was marked as correct by my professor.

My question though is regarding the use of the empty string. I wasn't sure if including the empty string in the derivations was correct, but it was the pattern used in some examples I've seen and I followed that usage thinking that including the empty string was expected (or implied) in every factored derivation.

But when I asked the professor for clarification on that point he stated that the empty string is **not** implied in every derivation, and its usage has important connotations and is rarely used.

So given that:

1. **What is the importance of the empty string in CFG derivations?** I read that it is used to "erase" a LHS, presumably to terminate derivation and proceed to the next derivation? But I'm not clear on if there is more to it than that.
2. If the empty string is rarely used in a derivation or factored derivation, ***when* is it actually meant to be used?** If it should be used sparingly I'd like to have some guidance on that so I don't just litter my derivations with it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much of an answerable question here. You seem to be asking of what use, intuitively, a certain syntactic construct is. I don't think there's a clear answer: we know (by CNF and GNF) that we don't *need* $\varepsilon$-rules for anything but deriving the empty word (in the context-free realm, that is) but they may come in handy. This is similar to using non-determinism in finite automata. When and how to use such superfluous features is a matter of taste -- hence there is no objective answer.

Comment: @Raphael I get what you are saying. Maybe I'm just not able to ask the question more clearly because I'm still learning the topic. What I'm trying to get at is, when I see derivations in a CFG, why are empty strings used in some derivations but not others? What is the empty string supposed to signal to the parser when processing the input string against the specified language? There has to be a purpose for it to be there, I'm just not clear on what that purpose is, and therefore not sure when I should include it and when to leave it out. Does that make more sense? Thanks.

Comment: @Raphael Again, I'm not questioning the need/non-need of the construct from a math/theory perspective. Clearly that was established by the other question's answers that it isn't strictly required. I'm seeking to understand why I would/should/must include it in a CFG and what impact it has on the parsing process. It isn't clear if it signals the end of the current derivation (and thus the parser should continue to the next token), or if it signals the termination of the entire input string, or some other purpose. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: "There has to be a purpose for it to be there" -- why does there have to be a deeper reason? If you looks at the standard parsing algorithms, I think you'll find that, quite clearly, $\varepsilon$ doesn't "signal" anything; it does not have a special meaning in this sense. In fact, it can invite trouble (as it is easy to make a grammar ambiguous by accident). So, imho, the answer here is "no" but it's probably impossible to prove that to you, because your question is not a formal one.

Comment: @Raphael I just realized what I think is happening. The empty string (when used in a recursive derivation) is a way to denote a derivation that can produce 0..m recursive productions of itself. Hence a grammar ab* can be created through $A \rightarrow aA'$ and $A' \rightarrow bA' | \epsilon$. This allows generation of strings $a$ as well as $ab...$ for $b$ repeated an arbitrary number of times. Is that a reasonable understanding?

Comment: @Dave: The only real answer is that an empty production indicates that a non-terminal could derive the empty string. For example, given $OptionalNumber \to Number | \epsilon$, the difference between $ExitStatement \to "exit" Number$ and $ExitStatement \to "exit" OptionalNumber$ should be obvious. Clearly, it would be easy to avoid the use of the epsilon rule here, but it seems more intuitive this way, no?

Comment: @rici Yes that makes sense and is generally what I was getting. I was trying to see if there was some underlying "rule of thumb" or pattern (in the software engineering sense) that called for using it to create a desired effect. As in "if you want to do X in Y way, be sure to include the epsilon in the derivation" etc. But it looks like such a thing doesn't explicitly exist, and may just be due to me only just now having a tiny exposure to language theory and not mastery of it. But then, asking questions is how we learn, hence my questions. Oh well.

Comment: 1) Your recursive rule works perfectly (if not exactly equivalently) without the empty word: $A \to aA \mid a$. 2) Well, I've told you "no"; now it's your turn to work with that. Keep in mind that in CS (or any science) it's rarely about fixed patterns or rules; if you have such, it's almost too boring to talk about! ;)

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to formal CS but have been programming (off and on) for many years, hence my search for "rules." So it looks like this is just a matter of me not having the right approach for this problem domain. Will definitely keep your point in mind, that is exactly the type of domain insight I'm trying to learn going forward. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually you are asking about the empty string in *rules*, not in *derivations*. Obviously it is not necessary, because there are algorithms to eliminate it. However, it might come in handy when contructing a grammar for a language. So if it does not increase the power, why not allow it in the general definition? I am not sure whether one could find examples of languages that cannot be generated by a grammar with N rules if the empty production is not allowed, but can be generated with N rules if this is allowed,